# Slot Machine Project utilizing arrays and methods in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

Write the body of the method int calculateWinnings(int[] wheelNums).

• Assume the input array has three elements and check it for each winning condition.
Return the correct number of tokens for each case.

• Print the notification that corresponds to the number of tokens returned

---

I'm no fast thinker but I usually have ideas.
basically, this is just one method that will be called from the MAIN method.
For now, I just want to understand and solve the bullet points.

I thought of using for loops with counters to take account of conditions such as the sequence of a 3 slot machine. 
Assume there are OTHER METHODS that take care of what's left than this method. 
**HERE IS THE SAMPLE OUTPUT:**
**NOTE BOLD IS THE USER INPUT**

- Java Slot Machine
- ---
- Tokens: 10
- Press enter to play (spend 1 token) or type 'quit' to stop.
- Spin: [3, 6, 7]
- Sorry, you lost :(
- Tokens: 9
- Press enter to play (spend 1 token) or type 'quit' to stop.
- Spin: [2, 4, 2]
- Pair! You win 1 token.
- Tokens: 9
- Press enter to play (spend 1 token) or type 'quit' to stop.
- Spin: [3, 2, 4]
- Sequence! You win 2 tokens.
- Tokens: 10
- Press enter to play (spend 1 token) or type 'quit' to stop.
- Spin: [4, 4, 4]
- Triple 4s! You win 12 tokens.
- Tokens: 21
- Press enter to play (spend 1 token) or type 'quit' to stop.
- **quit**
- You quit with 21 token(s).
- Your net profit is 11 token(s).

Comment: Can you please show the code you have so far?

Comment: public static int calculateWinnings(int[] wheelNums) {                                           
 // brainstorming comment! I was thinking of using a for loop to count the winnings                                                                                                                   
 }

Comment: Hint: you probably don't need a for loop within that method. Only outside when you are "pressing enter to play"

Comment: I'm probably using if conditions to count my winnings and return wheelNums?

Comment: You'd return the number of tokens not the input